# Is there another way to continue executing a function after return?

Tags: php

I want to return false to a user (which has a very large data to be processed) rather than waiting for the actual data to finish processing, the **FALSE means that the data is already in progress** and the user can now go **offline** to check later.

**NOTE:** user is a mobile app user (client).

Basically the code looks like this:

```
function accept_data($data){
 if(is_this_data_already_processed($data)) {
  return true;
 } else { 
  return false;
  now_process_data($data);
 }
}
```

By the time the user checks the data again, it will call the function `is_this_data_already_processed()`. If true, then it's processed.

I know that return statement terminates all executions. Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: `now_process_data($data);` will never be executed, I don't know what this function exactly does, but out the `return false` underneath of it

Comment: put your return false; below the now_process_data($data)

Comment: what type of entity is the "client" in the situation?

Comment: is the question not clear? is there a way/alternative to execute `now_process_data($data)` after `return false`?

Comment: You could however, use `ajax` to do this, or just `echo()` BEFORE calling `now_process_data()`

Comment: It *might* be possible to achieve what you want by using [goto](http://php.net/goto) but I have never used it since it is considered a bad practice. Other than that, you should probably change your code logic

Comment: Don't use `goto`, if you have to it means your code needs a re-read

Comment: I've been taught (and tell others) is to do `exit;` after a `header()` redirect so as to stop possible execution of script after the `header()`. I can't say it would for sure work but you could try doing a redirect to a new page above your `now_process_data` function and see if the function continues to process....might be a bad idea, I dunno. Probably not an ideal way to do it if it does work....which there's no guarantee it would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out what I needed was just to create another function:

```
function accept_data($data){
 if(is_this_data_already_processed($data)) {
  return true;
  // return true to user
  // user can now go offline
 } else { 
  data_not_processed();
  // return false to user
  // user can now go offline while data is being processed
  // and not wait to the process to finish
  now_process_data($data);
 }
}

function data_not_processed(){
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You won't pull this off without some kind of background task running utility.  But you also need to be able to determine if the process is already running, otherwise your code will re-run the process every time it is checked, even if it has already started.

```
define('PROCESS_STATE_SLEEP',   0);
define('PROCESS_STATE_RUNNING', 1);

function accept_data($data)
{
    if (is_this_data_already_processed($data)) {
        return true;
    }

    // determine if the process is already running, or not,
    // if not, start running.
    if (get_process_state($data) === PROCESS_STATE_SLEEP) {

        // initiate a background process, such as a gearman worker, 
        // amqp, or background exec
        now_process_data($data);
    }

    return false;
}
```

If your "client" is someone on a web browser, they won't get a response before the process is finished, even if you somehow return `false` before running it.

The process itself needs to be delegated to another process that can continue after the request is completed.